# does pandas have function similar to rowSums in R

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have dataframe:

df:

```
customer    sample1     sample2 sample3 sample4
costprice1  10  21  32  43
costprice2  12  24  15  18
costprice3  1   2   15  8
costprice4  16  30  44  58
costprice5  18  33  48  63
costprice6  20  36  52  68
costprice7  22  39  56  73
costprice8  24  42  60  78
costprice9  26  45  64  83
costprice10 28  48  68  88
```

i would like to drop rows that have values less than 15 in more than 2 columns

so this would be dropped

```
costprice3  1   2   15  8
```

In R we can do

```
df[rowSums(df < 15) <=2 , , drop = FALSE]
```

Can this be done in pandas, i have used pandas any to filter out rows only

```
df_fitered = df[(df > threshold).any(1)]
```

Comment: Use `sum` with `axis=1`. `df[df.lt(15).sum(1).le(2)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [16]: df[df.select_dtypes(['number']).lt(15).sum(axis=1) < 3]
Out[16]:
      customer  sample1  sample2  sample3  sample4
0   costprice1       10       21       32       43
1   costprice2       12       24       15       18
3   costprice4       16       30       44       58
4   costprice5       18       33       48       63
5   costprice6       20       36       52       68
6   costprice7       22       39       56       73
7   costprice8       24       42       60       78
8   costprice9       26       45       64       83
9  costprice10       28       48       68       88
```

Bonus answer:

```
mask = <condition1>
df[mask & (df.select_dtypes(['number']).lt(15).sum(axis=1) < 3)]
```

Comment: secondary question: if i have 20 rows out of which only 10 of them is where i need to check for this condition, is there a way to assign which rows to check for? I should have asked this in the main question.